# Amplify Vue amplify-authenticator component not displaying

Tags: vue.js, aws-amplify

I have been using an `<amplify-authenticator>` component on the `Home.vue` view of a web application, via the `HelloWorld.vue` component. This was working as expected, with signedIn state monitored using store.js and Vuex.

I have now switched to routing to `Home.vue` or `Login.vue` depending on sign-in state.

However, when a signed out user correctly routes to `Login.vue`, the page displays as expected, minus the `<amplify-authenticator>` component. It is clear from the Styles that this is importing (amazonOrange is listed as a color), but for some reason the sign-in interface is no longer displaying correctly.

**Login.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="login">
    <div>
      <vue-headful title="Login"/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <p>
      <router-link to="/">Login</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png" /></p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <amplify-authenticator></amplify-authenticator>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import { AmplifyEventBus } from "aws-amplify-vue";
export default {
  name: "Login",
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
};
</script>
```

If I change `amplify-authenticator` to `amplify-sign-in` then I see a sign in interface, but this needs additional scripting to implement.

I'd like to know specifically why the Authenticator component isn't displaying, since I cannot see an obvious bug in my code.

Comment: Does `HelloWorld.vue` import the `amplify-authenticator` component and list it in its `components` property? If not, then how and where is that component registered?

Comment: I think this line in main.js deals with it: `Vue.use(AmplifyPlugin, AmplifyModules, BootstrapVue);` the `<amplify-sign-in>` displays correctly without any additional imports, so I don't think it's an import issue. Certainly HelloWorld.vue wasn't importing anything different. The only difference I can see is that HelloWorld.vue was a component, whereas Login.vue is a view. I'm building upon this example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFftniOvoLA

Comment: Thanks for verifying. There's no difference between components and _views_, it's just a semantic folder name

Comment: Oh wait, you can't pass multiple plugins to [`Vue.use()`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-use). Each has to be on its own, the second argument is _options_, ie `Vue.use(AmplifyPlugin, AmplifyModules); Vue.use(BootstrapVue);`

Comment: Thanks, that was something I changed when I was trying to fix the problem! It isn't the cause of the problem, though, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. If the user is signed in to Amazon Cognito, then the `<amplify-authenticator>` will not display. The problem was with a bug in the check on `signedIn` state, which was redirecting the user to the wrong page.